# Adding point to a Polygon results in a star-shape in Google Maps Android

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I try to create a closed polygon in Android that expands if the user touches the screen and adds a new point to the polygon. But instead of an *area* I get a star-shape using the first coordinate as center point.

I used the following code:

```
@Override
  public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng)
  {

    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    //Toast.makeText(this,latLng.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if(shape==null)
    {
      shape=googleMap.addPolygon(new PolygonOptions()
              .add(latLng)
 .strokeColor(Color.RED));
      //line.setGeodesic(true);
    }
    else
    {
      List<LatLng> points=shape.getPoints();
      points.add(latLng);
      shape.setPoints(points);
    }
  }
```

What should I change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the auto-close feature. It automatically adds the first coordinate to make the polygon closed.

Here you can see, how the points are added by each click:

```
01-25 18:48:59.976  12761-12761/com.example.GoogleMapsTest W/DEBUG﹕ lat/lng: (-15.284186084328875,-28.12501810491085)
01-25 18:49:04.367  12761-12761/com.example.GoogleMapsTest W/DEBUG﹕ -------------------
01-25 18:49:04.367  12761-12761/com.example.GoogleMapsTest W/DEBUG﹕ lat/lng: (-15.284186084328875,-28.12501810491085)
01-25 18:49:04.375  12761-12761/com.example.GoogleMapsTest W/DEBUG﹕ lat/lng: (16.29905262358862,-38.32033362239599)
01-25 18:49:09.312  12761-12761/com.example.GoogleMapsTest W/DEBUG﹕ -------------------
01-25 18:49:09.312  12761-12761/com.example.GoogleMapsTest W/DEBUG﹕ lat/lng: (-15.284186084328875,-28.12501810491085)
01-25 18:49:09.312  12761-12761/com.example.GoogleMapsTest W/DEBUG﹕ lat/lng: (16.29905262358862,-38.32033362239599)
01-25 18:49:09.312  12761-12761/com.example.GoogleMapsTest W/DEBUG﹕ lat/lng: (-15.284186084328875,-28.12501810491085)
01-25 18:49:09.312  12761-12761/com.example.GoogleMapsTest W/DEBUG﹕ lat/lng: (26.115986226379576,-1.0547062754631042)
01-25 18:49:12.421  12761-12761/com.example.GoogleMapsTest W/DEBUG﹕ -------------------
01-25 18:49:12.421  12761-12761/com.example.GoogleMapsTest W/DEBUG﹕ lat/lng: (-15.284186084328875,-28.12501810491085)
01-25 18:49:12.421  12761-12761/com.example.GoogleMapsTest W/DEBUG﹕ lat/lng: (16.29905262358862,-38.32033362239599)
01-25 18:49:12.421  12761-12761/com.example.GoogleMapsTest W/DEBUG﹕ lat/lng: (-15.284186084328875,-28.12501810491085)
01-25 18:49:12.421  12761-12761/com.example.GoogleMapsTest W/DEBUG﹕ lat/lng: (26.115986226379576,-1.0547062754631042)
01-25 18:49:12.421  12761-12761/com.example.GoogleMapsTest W/DEBUG﹕ lat/lng: (-15.284186084328875,-28.12501810491085)
01-25 18:49:12.421  12761-12761/com.example.GoogleMapsTest W/DEBUG﹕ lat/lng: (-25.79989178579966,15.46873524785042)
```

So if you want to make a dynamic polygon, remove the automatically added point by adding this line:

```
 if(points.size()>2)
      points.remove(points.size()-2);
```

Comment: That's ugly. They should return exactly the same array you send via `setPoints`.

Comment: I modify the point list and then set it via setPoints after that. If this is ugly, how would you prevent the start-shape?

Comment: I meant what the API does is ugly/unintuitive. It should not modify the list that you send to it. Btw. you may want to accept your answer.

Comment: I agree with MaciejGorski, that's not a feature, that's a bug / bad design. I reported it here : https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7375&thanks=7375&ts=1416617179 Please feel free to star it...

Answer (score 0):

You can below changes to the code:

```
 void addNewPointtoPolygon(LatLng point,Polygon plg){
    List<LatLng> lll = plg.getPoints();
    if (lll.size() < 2)
        lll.add(point);
    else lll.add(lll.size() - 1, point);
    plg.setPoints(lll);
}
```